# print directly with html5 or javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vb.net, html

I'm looking for some way in which you can print a ticket automatically, not even them any way possible. I tell them what I try so far.

1. kiosk, really dont know how it work, but I tried putting a shortcut with the target: `--kiosk  --kiosk-printing <my url>` in chrome version 41.0.2272.89, only open the page and the print windows appers, (note my url) = windows.print

2.- every possible way with javascript, html and more, believe me so much more... etc.

3- I created my own automatic printing system,

3.1 I wanted to print the data were saved in a .txt file,

3.2. i Create a vb.net application that verifies file.txt modifications (changes in the .txt file)

3.3 vb.net application reads the data and then prints them, and then deletes the print data

this work very nice, the problem is in my pc (server/client) work fine, is becouse i write the .txt with php, i know i fail, but now i looking a way to print directly with 4 method, or find the form for write the .txt in client side(html5, javascript, angularjs, GOD ...etc!, becouse i cant find the method for write automatic(that is necesary).

please help me

Answer (score 0):

I used once a plugin for firefox that disabled the confirmation prompt when the print command is called.

The extension's name is **JS Printer Setup**.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/

With this plugin you can configure every parameter of printer configuration with no need to access the printer configuration box.

In order to hide the confirmation box, you need to install the plugin e add a Javascript into your web page with these commands:

```
<script>
// set portrait orientation
jsPrintSetup.setOption('orientation', jsPrintSetup.kPortraitOrientation);
// set top margins in millimeters
jsPrintSetup.setOption('marginTop', 15);
jsPrintSetup.setOption('marginBottom', 15);
jsPrintSetup.setOption('marginLeft', 20);
jsPrintSetup.setOption(' marginRight', 10);
// set page header
jsPrintSetup.setOption('headerStrLeft', 'My custom header');
jsPrintSetup.setOption('headerStrCenter', '');
jsPrintSetup.setOption('headerStrRight', '&PT');
// set empty page footer
jsPrintSetup.setOption('footerStrLeft', '');
jsPrintSetup.setOption('footerStrCenter', '');
jsPrintSetup.setOption('footerStrRight', '');
// Suppress print dialog
jsPrintSetup.setSilentPrint(true);
// Do Print
jsPrintSetup.print();
// Restore print dialog
**jsPrintSetup.setSilentPrint(true);** //This part has to be true
</script>
```

However I resolved all my problems, as well as you, creating an app (client/server) that reads an URL, every 30 seconds, that provides a json with all information needed to create a printer job.

Another approach is create an app client and another server using sockets. When a new information to print arrives, the socket server sends the information and the client would do the rest.

Comment: I think in that too , becouse my web is connected to server but ...no is a good idea, i cant understand why is so hard do it

Comment: You know any method for write a txt file with js?

Answer (score -1):

Please check this - https://qz.io/

It uses a java applet to send print requests to any printer you want without using the browser print dialog.

Note that, as it is Java, it gets blocked by default, which can be a pain.
Other than that, my company is using it since 05/2013 and it works great.

By the way, browsers can't print without user interaction for security reasons. If a browser could access any component on a computer without the user knowing, it would be mayhem.